# how to select current and past month-year in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i am using `date_select` to select month and year but by default this is able to select future month and year. i want to restrict selection of future month and year. how can do this in rails?

here is my current code-

```
        <div class="field medium-4 columns">
          <%= form.label :attendance_month %>
          <%= form.date_select :attendance_month, { :discard_day => true, :discard_month => false, :discard_year => false },:class => 'month-and-year' %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With :date_select you are unable to specify an 'end_month', instead I would create a helper method:

```
# app/helpers/some_helper.rb
module SomeHelper
  def month_range
    ( Date.today.at_beginning_of_year..Date.today ).each_with_object( [] ) do | date , month_array |
       month_array << date.strftime( "%B %Y" ) 
      end.uniq
  end
end
```

and then I would use month_range as part of a select_tag:

```
<%= form.select :attendance_month, month_range, :class => 'month-and-year' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict selection of dates by passing in end_year.

```
:end_year => Time.now.year
```

Further reading:

[Action View Date Helpers:date_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select)

> :end_year - Set the end year for the year select. Default is Date.today.year + 5 if you are creating new record. While editing existing record, :end_year defaults to the current selected year plus 5.

Comment: year is working but what about ```month``` in 2020 month is from JAN- DEC. it should be JAN- JUN

Comment: I have written a new answer to deal with this different scenario.